# json parser using threads, wont go into the run method android

Tags: java, android, json, threadpool

i am new to programming and I am making a json parser, but my thread method is not accessible, how do I go about doing this. When I debug, it goes into my getjson method but then skips the run method. 
I searched on stack over flow already but I am very confused about threading is there any good way to do this?

```
public class jsonParser {
 static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";
    // constructor
    public jsonParser() {

    }

    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(final String url) {

         Thread t = new Thread() {

public  void run() {
Looper.prepare(); //For Preparing Message Pool for the child Thread
       // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();           

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object

            try {jObj = new JSONObject(json);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());     
                 }
            Looper.loop(); 
       return;     
      }
}; t.start();
return jObj;      
         }
                }
```

Comment: Did you try gson library ?

Comment: The point about threading is to run things parallel... You only can debug one thread, so while you are debugging your main thread your other thread is running parallel without you seeing it. Put a breakpoint within your run method and you will see that your run method IS running. Consider having a look for some tutorials about threading.

Comment: hey! it doesn't hit the IS running field, I am not sure how to move forward.

Answer (score 0):

It goes to the `run()` method. But the principle of a thread is that it's executed in parallel to the current thread. So here's what happens on the time line:

```
main thread
_______________________________________________________________________
    |                    |
    start parser thread  return jObj

parser thread
      _________________________________________________________________
       |                                                       |
       execute an HTTP request and parse json                  assign JSON object to jObj
```

When you return `jObj` from the current thread, you have just started the parser thread. Maybe it hasn't even started executing yet. Maybe it's still waiting for the HTTP response. What's sure is that there is 0% chance that it has finished executing and stored the result in the static jObj variable yet. So, the value returned from the current thread is null.

It's hard to tell you what you should do, except read more on threading and on the supporting classes provided by android.

Comment: thank you so much for the clarity could you suggest any other way to do this?

Comment: First of all, don't use unsynchronized static variables to share state between threads. Only use local variables. I don't know what you're trying to achieve, but the current thread should not return anything from this method. Instead, the parser thread should call some callback method when it has finished parsing the JSON (like for example, log it or display it on the screen).